# How to compile picoProlog from source code?

Tags: c, prolog, pascal

I am a student in Computer Science, and I am learning about logic programming with Prolog.

I have found an interesting Prolog interpreter, **picoProlog** (http://spivey.oriel.ox.ac.uk/corner/Logic_Programming).

To know more about Prolog, I am trying to compile their source code, but I failed.

In this web page, they said:

> The interpreter source is written in a minimal dialect of Pascal, avoiding many features including pointers, but using macros to overcome some of Pascal's limitations, in a style inspired by Kernighan and Plauger's book Software tools in Pascal. It comes with a translator from the Pascal dialect into C that can be used to build the interpreter and also source for the macro processor that is needed.
>
> **To build the interpreter on a Linux machine**, just extract the tar file and type make. The building happens in several stages:
>
> 1. First, the Pascal-to-C translator ptc is built from C source, including a lexer and parser written with lex and yacc. The file README gives some details of the very restricted Pascal subset accepted by this translator.
> 2. Next, ptc is used to build the macro processor ppp.
> 3. Finally, the picoProlog interpreter is built from the source code in the file pprolog.x by first expanding macros using ppp to obtain a file pprolog.p, then translating to C with ptc, and lastly compiling the C code.
>
> Text and software copyright © J. M. Spivey, 1996, 2002, 2010.

They said about **compiling on Linux only**, so I don't know how to compile this source code in Windows machine. Can I compile it with **Turbo Pascal 7.0** (without any requirement) on **Windows XP**? Can you remove some part of script for **Pascal compiling** only?

Comment: [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) may work as a replacement of a Linux machine, it hopefully provides all the tools required, can't say for sure

Comment: you can't. a preprocessor is needed. it's not pure pascal (see step 3 in the instructions you posted)

Comment: Let's step back for a minute. What's the specific purpose of using Turbo Pascal 7 here? That compiler was discontinued in 1995; it has been obsolete for more than twenty years.

Comment: @duskwuff, in my country, **Turbo Pascal 7** is used as an **educational programming language**. Can you help me?

Comment: Turbo Pascal is not possible. Its limited memory model prohibits the 1MB allocations done in this source. Still it is mostly the same dialect, see the Free Pascal post.

Comment: Btw why was the last post deleted?

Comment: Turbo Pascal is entirely possible, if you reduce the sizes of the tables to suit, and a usable Prolog system results (for small programs, anyway).

Answer (score 5):

I found this question while googling, and though it's old, I thought it would be helpful to add a definitive answer from the author of the program.

It is indeed not too hard to get picoProlog to compile with the Free Pascal Compiler.  I've incorporated Marco's suggestions into the source, fixed a small bug that was revealed, and added a workaround for an odd feature of Free Pascal.  The results can be found on the GitHub page:

https://github.com/Spivoxity/pprolog

with instructions for building in the README.

Note: I built this with Free Pascal under Linux on x86_64, but haven't tested it on Windows.  I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Edit 18 Oct 2022 -- Replaced BitBucket with GitHub.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid spending more time in getting the P2C/PTC bootstrapping to run while you are probably only interested in the interpreter and not its *nix bootstrapping, I think it is easier to forget the PTC stuff and focus getting the pascal parts to compile/work with FPC 2.6.x. (the below took 10 minutes), generating a standalone Windows EXE with 10-20 code line additions.

Start with ppp, hmm, that compiles (nand works!) out of the box:

```
D:\dls\prlg\pprolog>fpc ppp.p
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.2 [2013/02/12] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2012 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling ppp.p
Linking ppp.exe
394 lines compiled, 0.1 sec , 30352 bytes code, 1692 bytes data
```

The code does looks like it is meant to have its input piped in. We haul pprolog.x through it (ppp) and it (pprolog.pp) almost compiles. There are four problems, but all are fixable by adding some code to the top, and not changing original code (marked with MVDV: in the source)

1. Some range check errors because integer type is too small for the 1MB stackspace that is set up. This prohibits Turbo Pascal usage, but we can workaround it by defining integer as longint.
2. Seems it assumes that forward functions don't need their arguments repeated while in FPC they generally do, fixed.
3. In the final function of ("initialize") some non standard ptc library functions are used that borrow from C (argv, argc) instead of their typical pascal equivalents. Fixed.
4. (reported by original author after testing) ParseFactor has a right hand recursion that is substituted by reading
      the result. Enable TP mode ( {$mode tp} above the uses line), or add () to disambiguate

After these, pprolog.pp compiles with FPC:

```
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.2 [2013/02/12] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2012 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling pprolog.pp
pprolog.pp(487,19) Warning: unreachable code
pprolog.pp(532,19) Note: Local variable "dummy" is assigned but never used
Linking pprolog.exe
2150 lines compiled, 0.1 sec , 84400 bytes code, 13932 bytes data
1 warning(s) issued
1 note(s) issued
```

Some notes:

1. **UNTESTED**
2. I don't know if I got the range of argv/argc exactly right. (0..argc-1 while paramcount is 1-based etc) Check if necessary.
3. The string system predates the TP String type and is convoluted (probably because of PTC, see README), I don't know if it will work.

I've put the resulting, compiling source code at  http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/files/pprolog.pp

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for the useful code.  But there's still a problem that I found in testing it.  Free Pascal makes the name of a function into a variable for the whole body, not just on the LHS of assignments.  So there's a place where you have to write ParseTerm( ) to force a recursive call.

Comment: The non-standard string extensions of various Pascals are nice, but they typically allocate the maximum space to every string.  PicoProlog's "string system" (as you put it) does that with temporary strings, but packs all the permanent strings together inb one big array to save a lot of space.  It seems to work fine under FPC.

Comment: Mike Spivey: the returnvalue variable thing is one of the big differences between default and other modes. IIRC it shouldn't happen in strict TP mode ( -Mtp ).  FPC and Delphi have various kinds of strings. The old school TP so called "shortstring" always allocates everything. The newer ansistring is completely a heap construct. Which is "string" depends on mode and {$H} switch.

Comment: I checked but couldn't find a rhs recursive use of parseterm in function parseterm. (which seems very short and overviewable) Which line was it?

Comment: My mistake: it was in ParseFactor

https://bitbucket.org/Spivey/pprolog/commits/d67b9cecced9f8573fd26a25268cb24d2c567527

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm (by inspecting the generated assembler) that compiling in TP mode does not need adding the (). I added a {$mode tp} to the file on the site.

Comment: Please note the additional bugfix in LookUp included in the BitBucket commit.

Comment: If it is the if p=1 then p:=maxsymbols else p:=p-1 then I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Given how many different variations of Pascal have existed, my gut feeling is it's easier to get hold of a Linux environment than to adjust the Pascal source code to fit the compiler you have. And this is only the first step.

Getting a Linux environment? Try a virtualbox - https://www.virtualbox.org

Comment: It's not fit for any pascal compiler. It is pascal source modified for a specific version of ptc that is bundled though.  Reverting the unixisms introduced by that modification makes the source compiler with a modern compiler like Free Pascal.