# How to compile VTProlog from source code?

Tags: c, prolog, pascal

I am a student in Computer Science, and I am learning about logic programming with Prolog.

I have found an interesting Prolog interpreter, **VTProlog** (https://github.com/Johnicholas/Hello-Github/blob/master/prolog-in-hundreds-of-loc/vtprolog-in-c/vtprolog.pas).

To know more about Prolog, I am trying to compile their source code. And, I got success with **Turbo Pascal 7.0**, but failed with **Free Pascal 2.6.4**.

> - vtprolog.pas(1195,8) Error: Identifier not found "l"
> - vtprolog.pas(1198,30) Error: Identifier not found "l"
> - vtprolog.pas(1199,16) Error: Identifier not found "l"
> - vtprolog.pas(1203,34) Error: Identifier not found "l"
> - vtprolog.pas(1611) Fatal: There were 4 errors compiling module, stopping
> - vtprolog.pas(0) Fatal: Compilation aborted

Is there any way to compile it both with **Turbo Pascal 7.0** (without any requirement) or **Free Pascal 2.6.4** on **Windows XP**?

Comment: How can we tell you how to fix your problem with Free Pascal 2.6.4 if you don't tell us what went wrong?

Comment: And yes, I realize the duplicate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907432/how-to-compile-picoprolog-from-source-code) is a slightly different Prolog interpreter, but the basic problem is the same: Turbo Pascal 7.0 is ancient history.

Comment: Not really sure why this is marked as a duplicate when it is about issues with different compiler and a different code base. The OP doesn't have a problem with Turbo Pascal, but with Free Pascal which isn't outdated.

Comment: Fair enough; I've reopened. Still really weird that two questions both about Prolog interpreters written in Pascal show up at once like that.

Comment: @duskwuff Indeed. I didn't think Pascal was used in education anymore.

Comment: @jpw For some reason, a lot of Indian CS courses still use Turbo C++ and Turbo Pascal. It's pretty bizarre.

Comment: Russia and Brazil too afaik. It is considered an excellent choice because the IDE invites less play and training, leaving more hours for actual exercises, but that is a different decision. The base problem is that fpj wants to dig out 30+ years old source without being able to do a single modification to adapt for changes in syntax. That works with no language.

Comment: How about picking a different Prolog interpreter? If you want to learn Prolog, getting up-to-date tools is best... Or are you rather interested in how Prolog interpreters can be implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing too much about Pascal I think the problem is that part of **line 1159**:

`Procedure print_functor (* l : node_ptr *) ;`

has been commented out. Change that to:

`Procedure print_functor (l : node_ptr) ;`

and it should compile - at least it did when I tried with [Ideone](http://ideone.com/uJMWgJ) (using the Free Pascal Compiler). If the program will work as intended I can't say.

Answer (score 2):

Did you put Free Pascal in strict Turbo Pascal Mode with -Mtp ? If I do it compiles, even with older 2.6.2.

```
D:\testing>fpc vtprolog.pp -Mtp
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.2 [2013/02/12] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2012 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling vtprolog.pp
vtprolog.pp(222,3) Note: Local variable "num" is assigned but never used
vtprolog.pp(310,3) Note: Local variable "s" not used
vtprolog.pp(1253,13) Note: Local variable "p" not used
vtprolog.pp(100,3) Note: Local variable "source_file" not used
vtprolog.pp(102,13) Note: Local variable "text_chars" is assigned but never used
vtprolog.pp(103,46) Warning: Variable "HeapPtr" read but nowhere assigned
Linking vtprolog.exe
1610 lines compiled, 0.3 sec , 43712 bytes code, 2204 bytes data
1 warning(s) issued
5 note(s) issued
```

For ideone, you can simulate the commandline parameter by adding {$mode tp} as first thing in the file (before the (*$V-... *) line ). I tested it with ideone, and it [compiled](http://ideone.com/0875jj).